# Python numpy arange

Tags: python, numpy

Below code displays from 12.01 till 16.01. But shouldn't it display only till 16.00?

```
import numpy as np

for i in np.arange(12.01, (16.01), 0.01):
    print(float('{num:0.2f}'.format(num=i)))
```

Comment: print the whole range at once.

Comment: Using floating point in this way is not reliable.

Comment: Try adding `0.01` to `12.01` 400 times. It'll give you something slightly smaller than 16.01 (namely 16.009999999999916 on my machine) due to floating point arithmetic. Also maybe have a look at: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: You can also try: `16.02-0.01 == 16.009999999999998`

Comment: Use `decimal` [module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html) if you need decimals...

Answer (score 4):

From the [numpy.arange](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) documentation:

> When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent. It is better to use linspace for these cases.

So `linspace` might be more appropriate for your case

If you want 400 evenly spaced numbers from 12.01 to 16:

```
np.linspace(12.01, 16, num=400)
```

Comment: That documentation is simplifying :) The results are not "not consistent" – they *are* – but the implicitly applied accuracy of such floating point numbers is beyond normal human ken.